# Error al deployar app con wildfly 27

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-security, wildfly

Estoy tratando de levantar una aplicación con wilfly 27 y postgres desde jenkins pero al tratar de levantar me sale el error que adjunto en la imagen [image: imagen]

esto sucede después de que mapea la auditoria como se muestra en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo curioso es que localmente me funciona correctamente, por favor si alguien tiene idea de lo que puede ser le agradecería mucho.

Comment: Hola Jose, bienvenido, la pregunta/respuesta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, te sugiero que la edites, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, para que no sea cerrada, y evitar recibir votos negativos, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener una medalla!.